# Exported Mpeg Video ends up as .DVD file

Tags: export

When ever I try to export an Animation as an MPEG, it ends up as a .DVD File and is unplayable. Am I missing an option to fix it?

Comment: Unfortunately, outside of blender MPEG standards encompass a large number of formats (audio layer 1,2,3, AAC, MPEG 1 video, MPEG 2 video, MPEG program streams, MPEG transport streams, and then there's all the ISO 14496 stuff with H.264 video and MP4 containers).  Which of the many MPEG audio, video and container formats are you targeting?

Comment: See <a href="http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24756/when-exporting-an-h-264-video-why-is-the-resulting-files-extension-avi/">this question</a> for instructions to output an MPEG. BTW, you *can* play the `.dvd` file using VLC or by uploading to Google Drive or YouTube.

Comment: or manually put .mpg after the save file name you wish to save it as. before you render ;)

Comment: And disable the File Extension check box below so that it doesn't add frame numbers to the end.